# Stochastic Models (probability)- simple symmetric random walk question

Tags: probability, self-study, central-limit-theorem, stochastic-approximation

My study group and I are currently stumped on this  probability question related to Stochastic models.

Let {Xn} be a **simple symmetric random walk** (ie p = 1/2).
) 
Give an approximation of the probabilitythat Xn ∈ [−3√n, 2√n] for large n

We were able to get as far as here using the **central limit thereom**

Var(X1) = (−1)^2 P(X1 = −1) + 1^2 P(X1 = 1) = 1/2 + 1/2 = 1 
and so
P(Xn ∈ [−3√n, 2√n]) ~ P(N (0, 1) ∈ [−3, 2])
what do we summate to get the probablity though ?
Thank you

Comment: Add the self-study tag.

Comment: You don't need to sum anything: look the answer up in tables of the Normal distribution or with a suitable probability calculator like `R` or even [a Web applet.](http://www.rossmanchance.com/applets/NormCalc.html)

Answer (score 1):

The final position is $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, with mean $0$ and variance $n$ (and approximately normal). So, $$P(-3\sqrt{n}<X_n<2\sqrt{n})=P(-3<Z<2)=\Phi(2)-\Phi(-3)$$
where you can find $\phi$ function in normal tables or use a program as suggested in the comments.